# Why can't I uninstall mysql-5.5 & install mysql-5.6 on Amazon Linux machine?

Tags: yum, mysql5.5, mysql5.6

I'm on a 64-bit Amazon Linux machine.

I had previously installed mysql-server 5.5. (using `sudo yum install`)
However, I soon found out that my application requires MySql-serve 5.6.

So I uninstalled mysql-server 5.5. (using `sudo yum remove mysql-server`) and now I'm following [**these instruction**](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/26/install-mysql-server-5-6-in-centos-6-x-and-red-hat-6-x-linux/) to install mysql-server 5.6.

But I'm running into a problem.

when I try to do the second install, I get the following 2 errors:

```
file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 from install of mysql-community-libs-5.6.14-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55-libs-5.5.46-1.10.amzn1.x86_64
file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-community-server-5.6.14-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-config-5.5.46-1.10.amzn1.x86_64
```

Why on earth am I getting these two errors? How do I fix them?
I removed mysql-server-5.5, so why is it conflicting with 5.6?

I did `ls` on `/etc/my.cnf` and `/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18` and the files don't even exist!! If the files don't exist how can they be conflicting with other files?? Who can help explain this?

Comment: The messages name the specific packages in conflict.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I know. But why am I getting it since I removed mysql-5.5? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Because you didn't remove the conflicting packages!

Comment: I did remove one of the conflicting package. See the following from the original post: "I uninstalled mysql-server 5.5. (using `sudo yum remove mysql-server`)"

Comment: You probably need to remove mysql-client as well.  I would 'sudo yum list installed | grep mysql' and see if there are any other mysql packages installed.

Comment: @Doug, your comment helped me solve it!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Doug's answer helped me solve it:

> You probably need to remove mysql-client as well.  I would 'sudo yum
>   list installed | grep mysql' and see if there are any other mysql
>   packages installed.

Comment: Yes, those pesky clients will get you every time.